# When i upload the code to nodeMCU this error comes I have checked libraries ,ports made enviroment for nodemcu but error always come to screen

Tags: nodemcu, error

```
Arduino: 1.8.7 (Windows 10), Board: "NodeMCU 1.0 (ESP-12E Module), 80 MHz, Flash, Disabled (new aborts on oom), Disabled, All SSL ciphers (most compatible), 32KB cache + 32KB IRAM (balanced), Use pgm_read macros for IRAM/PROGMEM, 4MB (FS:2MB OTA:~1019KB), 2, v2 Lower Memory, Disabled, None, Only Sketch, 115200"

Executable segment sizes:


ICACHE : 32768           - flash instruction cache 


IROM   : 425200          - code in flash         (default or ICACHE_FLASH_ATTR) 


IRAM   : 29829   / 32768 - code in IRAM          (IRAM_ATTR, ISRs...) 


DATA   : 1664  )         - initialized variables (global, static) in RAM/HEAP 


RODATA : 7200  ) / 81920 - constants             (global, static) in RAM/HEAP 


BSS    : 28472 )         - zeroed variables      (global, static) in RAM/HEAP 


Sketch uses 463893 bytes (44%) of program storage space. Maximum is 1044464 bytes.
Global variables use 37336 bytes (45%) of dynamic memory, leaving 44584 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 81920 bytes.
esptool.py v3.0
Serial port COM6
Connecting....
Chip is ESP8266EX
Features: WiFi
WARNING: Detected crystal freq 255.46MHz is quite different to normalized freq 40MHz. Unsupported crystal in use?
Crystal is 40MHz
MAC: 44:17:93:11:8c:e4
Uploading stub...
Running stub...
Stub running...
Configuring flash size...
Auto-detected Flash size: 4MB
Compressed 468048 bytes to 339496...
Writing at 0x00000000... (4 %)
Writing at 0x00004000... (9 %)
Writing at 0x00008000... (14 %)
Writing at 0x0000c000... (19 %)
Writing at 0x00010000... (23 %)
Writing at 0x00014000... (28 %)
Writing at 0x00018000... (33 %)
Writing at 0x0001c000... (38 %)
Writing at 0x00020000... (42 %)
Writing at 0x00024000... (47 %)
Writing at 0x00028000... (52 %)
Writing at 0x0002c000... (57 %)
Writing at 0x00030000... (61 %)
Writing at 0x00034000... (66 %)
Writing at 0x00038000... (71 %)
Writing at 0x0003c000... (76 %)
Writing at 0x00040000... (80 %)
Writing at 0x00044000... (85 %)
Writing at 0x00048000... (90 %)
Writing at 0x0004c000... (95 %)
Writing at 0x00050000... (100 %)
An error occurred while uploading the sketch

This report would have more information with
"Show verbose output during compilation"
option enabled in File -> Preferences.
```

Comment: Are you sure you selected the correct board and partition scheme?

Comment: Welcome! I am not familiar with nodeMCU but your error sounds similar to what happens in Linux, the errors are sent to the error out which in your case may be the console. Sorry I do not have the time to get into this further but you have the manuals etc this should give you an idea of what to look for,

Comment: You might want to try to upload with verbose compilation on and then post the output, it might give us a better idea of your problem (Look at the preferences in the Arduino environment).